# How to get rid of spacing between ANTD card and it's border?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

For a quite a long time i was using ANTD cards.
But i noticed that when i using `bordered={true}` property on Antd cards.
I have border with slightly spacing from card itself [![enter image description here][1]][1]
I was wondering does anyone know is that a Bug, or those spacing supposed to be by Antd design.
And if anyone found a way how to get rid off it, `margin-top`, and `padding-top` didn't really helped.

I found the same issue on ANTD website, that must be a bug!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rg2X5.png

Comment: inspect element in your browser can be a powerful tool to debug styles in the dom. You can open it using `ctrl`+`shift`+`c` shortcut on most browsers.

Comment: I know about that, by i don't see this gap in debug

Comment: Maybe post a SS of the debug, or some code.